# Is it possible to develop Win8 apps in different IDE than Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, windows-8

As the title mentions I would like to develop a `html`/`css`/`js` app for `Windows8` but I'm not a fan of `Visual Studio` either the express or standard version when it comes to developing html.

Thus my question is with all the languages being open source is there a bundle or tutorial out there for other IDE's for example `Aptana Studio` so that you don't need to develop in VS?

Or if there isn't are there any hints from Microsoft of such a thing being released in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any editor you like to write apps. I personally use **VIM** for most of the code I write.

However in order to build the apps for Win8 you will have to use the compiler etc. tools that comes with .Net platform. You can use that tools from the console and thus you will avoid interaction with Visual Studio

Comment: So besides compiling them by hand as you could say, there is no other disadvantage the MS JS libraries can just as easily added to Aptana or Eclipse or Netbeans?

Comment: Of course. It is plain old html/css/javascript that you've normally use for web apps. A possible disadvantage could be that there might not be any/some intellisense.